# Creating a report from git logs

Tags: bash, git, github, awk, sed

The dream is to create a script to run through my repos and create a report. I would like the report to contain the repositories, their submodules, the merged PRs associated with each repo and a list of updated files for those PRs. This would be produced between two given dates on master. I have been looking at something like this (where the hash's represent the first merge on the first day and the last on the other):

```
git log --format='%h - %s' --stat a123456...c123456 > report
```

One of the issues I am having - and I am unsure of whether this can be done with git or whether it is better to manipulate the report afterwards - is that currently this brings back too much information. That is, I am getting a list of all files touched on each PR. What I would really like is a condensed list, where only the most recent update to a given file is listed. at the moment I am getting something like this:

> c123456 - this is the third merge (#3)   ../file4
>
> b123456 - this is the second merge (#2)   ../file1   ../file3
> ../file4
>
> a123456 - this is the first merge (#1)   ../file1   ../file2
> ../file3   ../file4
> where what I would really like is something like this:
>
> c123456 - this is the third merge (#3)   ../file4
>
> b123456 - this is the second merge (#2)   ../file1   ../file3
>
> a123456 - this is the first merge (#1)   ../file2

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", $i=!a[$i]++?($i ORS):""; print ""}' file

c123456 - this is the third merge (#3)
../file4

b123456 - this is the second merge (#2)
../file1
../file3

a123456 - this is the first merge (#1)
../file2
```